# modificar valor da variavel em Python

Tags: python, variáveis

Preciso que o valor que for escrito na variável "add_money" seja somado e adicionado na variável "saldo"

```
saldo = 0
op = input('O que deseja fazer? ') 
if op == 'add': add_money = int(input('Qual sera o valor? ')) 
add_money + saldo 
print(saldo)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa especificar a qual variável você deseja somar o saldo com o add_money

Tende desta maneira

```
saldo = 0
op = input('O que deseja fazer? ') 
if op == 'add': 
    add_money = int(input('Qual sera o valor? ')) 
    saldo = add_money + saldo 
    print(saldo)
```